# Can I measure how much storage does the doc_values of a given field take?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch-5

First little bit of background: 
I have a significant elasticsearch cluster with more than 20TB of primary data (and replication is a must). We are using SSDs so storage is not that cheap. After reindexing my data to elasticsearch 5.4.1 I noticed my data takes 30 % storage space more than it used to when using elastic 1.7.5. My guess is, that it is caused by `doc_values` being on by default when using `keyword` mapping type.

I would like to measure how much storage `doc_values` of a particular mapping `field` take? I know that I could index documents with two different `mappings` and measure the difference, but is there any easier and quicker way?

I checked `_cat` and `indices` apis and I couldn't find any storage detailed breakdown, only memory. Maybe I could just find doc_values files in the file system and measure those?

Because of particular plugins requirement I'm using version 5.4.1 of elasticsearch.

**edit1:**
Ok according to [lucene docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50DocValuesFormat.html) doc_values have following extensions

> .dvd: DocValues data
>   .dvm: DocValues metadata

I could measure the size of those files in the folder of a shard of a given index. Here example output:

```
399M    ./nodes/0/indices/O0qTaAQHSDOfEMSD-zZXTw/2/index/_qed_Lucene54_0.dvd
646M    ./nodes/0/indices/O0qTaAQHSDOfEMSD-zZXTw/2/index/_wux_Lucene54_0.dvd
185M    ./nodes/0/indices/O0qTaAQHSDOfEMSD-zZXTw/2/index/_yve_Lucene54_0.dvd
```

From what I see some indexes have more of those files and some less. Also not sure if I can find out which field are they belonging to, maybe all doc_values are stored together? Both data and metadata files seem to be binary so nothing I can extract from there.

**edit2**:
Taking naive approach of just measuring files i checked on one of my nodes:

```
$ du -h ~/elasticsearch/data -d 0
642G    /home/chimeo/elasticsearch/data
$ find ~/elasticsearch/data/ -name "*.dv[dm]" -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- --total -s | tail -1
75G     total
```

So that's almost 12% of all storage on that node. Here bash one liner to calculate ratio:

```
bc <<< "scale=2; "`find ~/elasticsearch/data/ -name "*.dv[dm]" -print0 | du -h --files0-from=- --total -s | tail -1 | cut -f 1 | tr -d G`/`du -h ~/elasticsearch/data -d 0 | cut -f 1 | tr -d G`
```

I run this one liner on my whole cluster and results where 0.11-0.12. To my surprise fielddata (.fdt) files take almost 40% of all storage.

Comment: It could be due to more segments in your new shards. can you compare it in both clusteres?
Is your data some time based data?

Comment: To be honest, many different things could change the size. When migrating, a mapping changed a little bit, also sharding is different etc. There are many variables here. It is possible that you are right and maybe the segment count is at fault here.

But what I'm trying to find in this question is how much can I save by turning off doc_values. On example node I checked, the `.dvm` files took 10% storage of the data folder.